the eigenvalue of the combination of multiplicative and additive rank 1 perturbation
Given:

$A$ and $B$ are both rank 1 matrices. They are both Hermitian.

Invetigate:
The eigenvalue of $A(B+sI)^{0.5}$.
I figured out that the eigenvalue of $A(A+sI)^{0.5}$ has a closed form of $y^H x \sqrt{s+y^Hx}$ where $A=xy^H$, but there seems isn't closed expression of $A(B+sI)^{0.5}$.
